# "permission denied" when converting ubuntu.iso to ubuntu.img

Tags: boot, permissions, iso

I'm trying to make my macbook a dual boot with ubuntu with a USB drive, but when I go to terminal and put in the command to convert the file from iso to img it just says permission denied, and so I have no idea what to do.

I dragged the downloaded version of ubuntu to the terminal and then entered the command given by the ubuntu website into the terminal:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/ubuntu.iso
```

and then it would say permission denied. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The `~/path/to/target.img` and `~/path/to/ubuntu.iso` are examples - you need to replace them with the actual path and filename you are using.

Comment: Okay, I'm really new to this. How would I do that?

Comment: Also, note that `hdiutil` is a MacOSX command so this is not actually a Ubuntu problem and might be considered off-topic.

Comment: Just use the name of the downloaded file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the iso file into your home directory and then open a terminal and type this:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ubuntu.img NAME_OF_DOWNLOADED_FILE.iso
```

substituting NAME_OF_DOWNLOADED_FILE.iso for the actual name. This should create the file `ubuntu.img`

Comment: As you're new to the site, I'll mention that if this works for you, then please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick symbol to the left.

Comment: Afte I have finished my download to test the command, you have answered the question. You're fast my friend +1 =)